# Is this a resumptive pronoun: a father who loves his children

Tags: relative-clauses

> **A father** should love **his** children.
> A father **who** loves **his** children would spend more time at home.

The 'his' in this case is not a resumptive pronoun, right? It was never intended to be replaced by the relative pronoun. I suppose this is a good test?

Comment: As a well-read native speaker I had to look up the meaning of 'resumptive pronoun', but, no, I don't think it is.

Comment: No, "his" bears no resemblance to a resumptive pronoun. Such pronouns are used in some languages instead of a gap in relative clauses, e.g. *"words or term which you may not understand them", where there should be a gap instead of "them". But they are ungrammatical in English.

Comment: Not a term in my native usage either, tho grammarians are often wiser. 

`Summary
In many introspective and corpus studies, inserting a resumptive pronoun in place of a gap in island-violating wh-dependency structures in English is said to amnesty, ameliorate, or repair the island violation, improving the acceptability of otherwise unacceptable structures. Most experimental studies on the acceptability of such resumptive structures, ....`

https://www.cambridge.org/core/books/abs/cambridge-handbook-of-experimental-syntax/resumptive-pronouns-in-english/756FA275B61C480D1612699CCE647A73

Comment: Almost every pronoun will show up after some gap. No gap, no need to use that substitute for the antecedent. The resumptive ones are optional, but close a question.

Comment: Why was the migrated to ELL?  It's plainly not suited to ELL. The basic analysis of grammar is a useful task for an English learner.  But this question is not about the basic grammar of English, but an exceptional situation which challenges conventional parsing methods.  There is no reason for an English learner to be studying this.

Comment: To the OP.  If you are *learning* English,  know that you have made a wrong turn and are now lost in the woods. If you get an answer to this question *you will not have improved your learning of English!* If you are no a learner of English, then this is a fairly interesting walk in those woods, and I apologise for your question being migrated here.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this technical question of English analysis is not suitable for English Learning

Comment: @JamesK My bad. I was expecting simple yes or no answers; I was not expecting to go so deep into the literature on grammar... Perhaps it does rightly belong to ELL...